# Can't display a record from Apex controller in a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

I have a lightning component and I need to display an asset from my Apex controller.

But in the view, there is nothing, the page is blank.

Can you tell me why please?

This is my code:
.View :

```
<aura:component controller="AssetDetailCtrl" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="anAsset" type="Asset" />

    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(anAsset))}">

            <lightning:formattedText value="{!anAsset.Name}" /><br/>
            <lightning:formattedText value="{!anAsset.Price}" /><br/>
            <lightning:formattedText value="{!anAsset.InstallDate}" /><br/>
            <lightning:formattedText value="{!anAsset.SerialNumber}" /><br/>

        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <lightning:formattedText value="{!$Label.c.NoAssetDetail}" />
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>    
</aura:component>
```

Javacript controller :

```
({
    doInit : function(component) {
        var assetID = '1234567890asdfghj';

            var action = component.get("c.getAssetDetail");
            action.setParams({
                "assetId": assetId
            });
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                var state = response.getState();
                console.log('state : ' + state);
                if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                    var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();
                    console.log(storeResponse);
                    component.set('v.anAssetName', storeResponse.Name);
                }
            });  

            $A.enqueueAction(action);        
    }
})
```

.Apex :

```
@AuraEnabled 
public static Asset getAssetDetail(String assetId){
   Asset result;

   if(!String.isBlank(assetId)){
        List<Asset> assetList = [
           SELECT Id, Name, Price, InstallDate, UsageEndDate, SerialNumber
           FROM Asset
           WHERE Id = :assetId
       ];

       if(assetList.size() == 1){
           result = assetList[0];
       }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Hey Aurelien, formatting tip - to get your code to come out right, select the whole block and press Ctrl-K or click the `{}` button.

Comment: `var assetID = '1234567890asdfghj';` is this valid Asset SF ID?

Comment: The id is a fake, it is just for the exemple but in real, it works.
I get my record from the Apex controller but I can't see in the view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you are accessing attribute in `lightning:formattedText` is bit wrong. We access attribute using a value provider [v.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_source.htm)

```
<lightning:formattedText value="{!v.anAsset.Name}" /><br/>
```

In your JS Code, you are setting `v.assetName` when you get success respone from Aura Method. It does not exists in your markup.

The only attribute that exists in your markup is `anAsset` of Type `Asset`. Thus your code will be

```
({
    doInit : function(component) {
        var assetID = '1234567890asdfghj';

            var action = component.get("c.getAssetDetail");
            action.setParams({
                "assetId": assetId
            });
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                var state = response.getState();
                console.log('state : ' + state);
                if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                    var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();
                    console.log(storeResponse);
                    component.set('v.anAsset', storeResponse);
                }
            });  

            $A.enqueueAction(action);        
    }
})
```

Comment: I am an idiot, I have forgotten to add the "v.", it works now, thank you.

Comment: I have forgotten to add the "v." to display the record. <lightning:formattedText value="{!v.anAsset.Name}" />

Comment: @AurélienLaval Just a note - when an answer solves your question, you may choose to accept it by clicking the check mark. This marks it as solved and gives both you and the answerer a bit of reputation. That's generally the Stack Exchange way, rather than commenting or posting the same answer.